# java.net.UnknownHostException after turning the firewall on [Debian 10]

Tags: debian, vpn, dns, java, firewall

## Intro

I have a microservice running inside a docker container and deployed on a VM with the Debian 10 OS. The server's IP address is 141.45.146.55.

The microservice exposes the following API:

```
GET https://<host>:8636/?username=<username>&password=<password>
```

which performs an LDAP authentication request against a LDAP Server on a different node lets say: ldaps://example.com:636. The IP address of example.com is 141.45.11.192 (thats the output of nslookup example.com on the server).

Everything works fine if the firewall on the server on which the microservice is running is off, but if I turn on the firewall I get the following exception on the miroservice while making the HTTP request:

```java
javax.naming.CommunicationException: example.com:636 [Root exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: example.com]
```

It seems that the firewall is blocking a connection between the microservice and the remote LDAP server with the host ldaps://example.com:636.

### Question

What kind of firewall rule I have to add to (or remove from) the firewall script in order to make this working? For the sake of completeness I add the firewall scripts content:

```bsh
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

#
# Allow only 141.45.x.x
#
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 141.45.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
#
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8636 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables-save > /etc/firewall.conf
#
echo -n "#"      > /etc/network/if-up.d/iptables
echo -n !       >> /etc/network/if-up.d/iptables
echo /bin/sh    >> /etc/network/if-up.d/iptables
echo "iptables-restore < /etc/firewall.conf" >> /etc/network/if-up.d/iptables
#
chmod +x /etc/network/if-up.d/iptables
#
```

**I also would like to mention that the mircoservice is running inside a docker container** and if I turn off the firewall and reboot the VM everything works fine, but when I turn on the firewall the microservice throws an java.net.UnknownHostException.

```bsh
root:~# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  141.45.0.0/16        anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8443 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8636 state NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER-USER (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.3           tcp dpt:postgresql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.4           tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:https

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

#### What I have did so far

I read the javadoc of `java.net.UnknownHostException`, it states:

> Thrown to indicate that the IP address of a host could not be determined.

So the idea was that the firewall is maybe blocking the DNS, so I tried `nslookup example.com` on the server where the microservice and firewall is running. Unfortunately nslookup works when the firewall is on. It resolves example.com.

I also tried the following rules:

```bsh
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --sport 636 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --sport 636 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 636 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 636 -j ACCEPT
```

But without success. The admin told me that should not be necessary because we are behind the firewall (inside the same network), but because I am the developer of the microservice and the admin is not familiar with docker its up to me to get the microservice running with the firewall switched on.

Any other ideas?
I'm afraid it has something to do with Docker, what do you think?

```bsh
docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                     COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS        PORTS                          
c67630f9118b   dawidlokiec/ldap-authentication-service   "/opt/docker/bin/lda…"   2 days ago   Up 18 hours   0.0.0.0:8636->443/tcp
and three other contains ...
```

Why there are some docker specific chains and the destination addresses are 172.18.0.X, its != 141.45.X.X. Its a problem?

Comment: I'd start by allowing 636 for both TCP and UDP.

Comment: I added `iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 636 -j ACCEPT` and `iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 636 -j ACCEPT` doesn't help. still get the exception unknow host

Comment: since you are allowing responses back in, it should be --sport not dport, unless the ldaps service is running on the box in question. or were you trying to add an output rule?

Comment: Don’t use chain policies. Use explicit drop rules. Then use `iptables -vnL` to see which rules are matching. // Your state-matching rule should probably be `RELATED,ESTABLISHED` by the way.

Comment: @FrankThomas sorry its the first time that I use iptables, with --sport it also doen't work. I updated my question with more details and apologies with remote LDAP server I mean the companie's LDAP Server on another node inside the same network. Have you maybe another ideas?

Comment: @DanielB Unfortunately the admin wrote this script, as a junior software developer I am not familiar with iptables, but I have to get it run. What exactly do you mean by RELATED, on which line I have to change thaht? I also updated my question with more details, maybe you have more suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: look at your dmesg. what logs are you getting related to the failures? firewall logs are generally pretty complete, just to aid this kind of troubleshooting.